# Applied CSS causes anchors to be unclickable

Tags: html, css, django

I have come across a very odd issue, I have noticed that all of a sudden my anchors stopped working, as in became unclickable. Then I figured it must be something related to applied CSS, and when I started disabling parts of my CSS, I narrowed down the issue to this couple of lines:

```
.content {
    width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

My page structure looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>CoinShop v1.0</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/pages/css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/pages/css/navbar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/pages/css/base.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/pages/css/searchbar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/pages/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/products/css/detail.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='top-grid'>
      <div class='branding-grid-container'>
        <div class='branding-grid'>
          <div class='branding-grid-buttons-not-authenticated'>
            <a href="/help/" class='button-help'>Help</a>
            <a href="/accounts/register/" class='button-register'>Register</a>
            <a href="/accounts/login/" class='button-login'>Login</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='nav-grid'>
        <div class='search-bar'>
          <form action="/shop/" method="GET">
            <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search" class='search-box'>
            <input type="submit" value='Search' class='search-button'>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class='nav-bar'>
          <nav>
            <ul id='menu'>
              <li class='menu-item'><a href="/">Home</a></li>
              <li class='menu-item'><a href="/shop">Shop</a></li>
              <li class='menu-item'><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
              <li class='menu-item'><a href="/about">About</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='content'>
      <a href="/shop/1/">spam (2018)</a>
      <h1>spam (2018)</h1>
      <p>eggs</p>
      <p>Price: 200.00</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

...and all applied CSS combined looks like this:

```
.top-grid {
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #3D005A;
}

.branding-grid-container {
    background-color: #4e0e7c;    
}

.branding-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 400px;
    height: 6em;    
    background-color: #4e0e7c;
    margin: auto;
    width: 960px;
}

.branding-grid-buttons-not-authenticated {
    margin-top: 40px;
    grid-column: 3;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
}

.branding-grid-buttons-not-authenticated a {
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.button-help {
    background-color: #36c1d4;
}

.button-help:hover {
    background-color: #2a99a8;
}

.button-register {
    background-color: #FF9900;
}

.button-register:hover {
    background-color: #FF6600;
}

.button-login {
    background-color: #75C10A;
}

.button-login:hover {
    background-color: #62a307;
}

.branding-grid-buttons-not-authenticated a:hover {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.branding-grid-buttons-authenticated {
    margin-top: 50px;
    grid-column: 3;
    text-align: right;
}

.buttons-authenticated li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.buttons-authenticated li a {
    color: white;
}

.buttons-authenticated li a:hover {
    color: #EC9419;
}

.nav-grid {
    background-color: #3D005A;
    position: relative;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    margin: auto;
    width: 960px;
    height: 2.7em;
}

.search-bar {
    margin-top: 6px;
}

.nav-bar {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    text-align: right;
}

.above-form {
    background-color: #f5f3f2;
    color: #FF6600;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.error-wrapper {
    background-color: #F2DEDE;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    color: #a94442;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.close-button {
    border: none;
    background-color: #F2DEDE;
    color: #a94442;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0;
}

.close-button:hover {
    color: #685863;
}
ul#menu {
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu-item {
    display: inline-block;
}

.menu-item > a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    min-width: 80px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu-item > a:hover {
    color: #EC9419;
    text-decoration: none;
    max-height: 30px;
}

.search-bar form { font-size: 0; }

.search-bar input {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 2em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 1rem;
}

.search-box {
    border: none;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border-radius: 0.5em 0 0 0.5em;
}

.search-button {
    background-color: #FF9900;
    border-radius: 0 0.5em 0.5em 0;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 0px 15px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.search-button:hover {
    background-color: #FF6600;
}

.search-bar {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;    
}

.content {
    width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Here is the [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6cp278v0/1/).

Why would this couple of lines cause such an issue? This has never occurred to me before.
In the fiddle removing those couple of lines doesn't resolve the issue, whilst in my original code my anchor becomes clickable once those two lines are removed.

I'm referring to `<a href="/shop/1/">spam (2018)</a>` anchor specifically which I have created for the purpose of this minimal example but I have more than one and they all don't work.

Comment: When you say they don't work, what do you mean?

Comment: From what I can see in your fiddle, it's the element search-bar above the anchor link that is overlapping it. My sugestion would be give the search-bar a height or give a margin-top to the anchor link.

Comment: @IainShelvington they don't work as in they are not clickable, you can't click on them, when you hover over an anchor the little pointing finger doesn't pop up.

Comment: @OsvaldoCorreia what height should I give it? Can you post an answer, I'll be glad to accept it.

Comment: Here is your fiddle with a padding-top applied to the .content: https://jsfiddle.net/mdvhyjs9/

Comment: @OsvaldoCorreia I would prefer to give search-bar a specific height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.content {
    width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Play with the value in padding-top until you're happy with it.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mdvhyjs9/

By your request:

```
.search-bar {
    margin-top: 6px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

Play with the value in height until you like it.

Comment: as I mentioned in the comments, I would prefer to give search-bar a specific height, but I'm not sure how much that height should be.

Comment: it's happy with even 1px, I'm not sure how much should I give it.

Comment: I always give at least the height of its inner elements, ergo my value 30px. Of course, that can change according to the design you're aiming for. My advice is check/inspect element with the developer tools of your browser and play with them... Link for more info: https://www.lifewire.com/get-inspect-element-tool-for-browser-756549